# An integral inequality with respect to $f$ and $f'$

Tags: integration, inequality

Assume $f \in C[0,1]$ and $f(0)=f(1)=-\frac{1}{6}$,show that:

$$\frac{1}{4}+2\int_0^1f(x)\text{d}x\leq \int_0^1(f'(x))^2\text{d}x$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Start with
$$\int_0^1 (f'(x) + x + b)^2 dx \ge 0\ \ \ \ \ \forall b\in\Bbb{R}$$

Use integration by parts along the way to convert $\int x f'(x) dx$ to $\int f(x) dx$, and finally, pick the value of $b$ that gives you the wanted inequality. (You will also be able to prove that, in some sense, this inequality cannot be improved.)